# How to get in samsung galaxy s6 actve

Tags: samsung, locked-out

I had made a password for my Samsung galaxy s6 and I forgot it a few hours later and I don't know how to get into my phone and the thing where it say to sign into google is no working either i have been locked out for 3 hours it is a very stressful problem to have because all I wanted to do was get into my phone so someone please help me (btw I have the active)

Comment: If you have a Samsung account, and your phone can still connect to the internet (WiFi or 3G/4G doesn't matter), [these instructions](http://gadgetguideonline.com/galaxys6/samsung-galaxy-s6-guides/how-to-unlock-samsung-galaxy-s6-and-s6-edge-if-you-forget-the-screen-lock-password-and-your-fingerprint-is-not-accepted-either/) may help you. Otherwise a [hard reset](http://gadgetguideonline.com/galaxys6/samsung-galaxy-s6-guides/how-to-boot-into-galaxy-s6-recovery-mode/) is likely your only remaining option.

Answer (score 0):

I made a video for a similar model -- https://youtu.be/_onTYkSUbr0

If this method doesn't help you I have tons of videos for many models, try looking at a few of my other Samsung videos and see if any of they help you. Feel free to ask for help on my channel if you get stuck.